# jQuery find not working correctly in Node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, jsdom

I'm using jQuery to query a dom created by [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom) in Node.js:

```
var html = '<p class="widget">one</p><p class="widget">two</p><p class="widget">three</p>';
var jsdom = require('jsdom');
var jquery = require('jquery');
var document = jsdom.jsdom(html);
var widgets = jquery(document.parentWindow).find('.widget');
var arr = widgets instanceof Array; //true
widgets.each(function() { }) //each is not defined, its not a jquery object
```

I know the document is good. It contains 3 elements with the class `widget`.

However, jQuery's [find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) function is returning a regular JS array of these dom elements, rather than a jQuery object that wraps a collection of dom elements. Obviously, with the return value being a JS array, I can't then chain more jQuery functions like `each`.

The error I get is:

`TypeError: Object [object HTMLDivElement],[object HTMLDivElement],[object HTMLDivElement] has no method 'each'`

Does anyone know what is happening here? Why does `find` not return a jQuery object? Am I missing something obvious or is it a bug?

Versions:
"jquery": "2.1.1",
"jsdom": "2.0.0",

Comment: I've moved your code out of a snippet as the snippet did nothing but throw errors about `require` not being defined.

Comment: Oh, thanks. Haven't posted in a while and wasn't sure about the preferred  way to include the code

Comment: As a test: When I try to append that specific HTML to `document`, it fails, but appending to the `body` element works. Possibly it is just not valid at that level. This *is* very strange.

Comment: I tried wrapping the html snippet in a full html doc structure including an HTML5 doctype and I get the same result

Comment: jQuery assigns find to Sizzle and then later extends find with the jQuery specific stuff. I've realized that for some reason the later extending part (jQuery.fn.extend find) isn't executing. Meaning the result I see is the data returned directly from Sizzle, not jQuery

Comment: What happens if you try `var widgets = jquery(document).find('.widget');`? Or does that not work? (I'm not familiar with jsdom)

Comment: This won't work, but see @Louis's answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works:

```
var html = '<p class="widget">one</p><p class="widget">two</p><p class="widget">three</p>';
var jsdom = require('jsdom');
var jquery = require('jquery');
var document = jsdom.jsdom(html);
var widgets = jquery(document.parentWindow)('.widget');
widgets.each(function() {
    console.log(this);
});
```

What happens is that `jquery()` returns what in a browser would be accessible as `window.jQuery`. So you are calling `jQuery.find`, which is not the same thing as using `jQuery().find`. The latter is calling `find` on in *instance* of a `jQuery` object. In the code above, I'm doing what we'd normally do in a browser as `$('.widget')`. You could also do this if you want to use `find`:

```
var widgets = jquery(document.parentWindow)(document).find('.widget');
```

Whereas `jQuery().find` is documented, I've not found documentation for `jQuery.find`. I believe it is a utility function not meant to be used outside jQuery's own code.

Comment: Thanks, yes it was my misunderstanding on how to use jquery in node